# Select instance/row with max field/column value per with field/column (group by)

Tags: django, django-orm

So, I have these models:

```py
class Computer(models.Model):
    hostname = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=6)
    <other computer info fields>

class ComputerRecord(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pc = models.ForeignKey(Computer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ts = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    <other computerrecord info fields>
```

I want to get the row / computerrecord instance that has the max `ts` for each `pc` (Computer model)

In sql would be something like this:

```sql
SELECT hub_computerrecord.*
FROM hub_computerrecord
JOIN (
    SELECT pc_id, MAX(ts) AS max_ts
    FROM hub_computerrecord
    GROUP BY pc_id
) AS maxs ON hub_computerrecord.pc_id = maxs.pc_id
WHERE hub_computerrecord.ts = maxs.max_ts;
```

Note (edit): There are lot of `ComputerRecord` instances (10000+) so anything too inefficient won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean field in ComputerRecord model, for e.g. max_status. Identify the record with max 'ts' value for Computer object and set it to True. so if you have 10000 records for a particular computer model one record will have True and all the rest 9999 records will have False in max_status field. This needs to be done only once for each computer model.

Next time when you are adding a new row in ComputerRecord model just compare 'ts' of the of new record to 'ts' of the existing record with max_status value as True. if new record has higher 'ts' value set max_status as True for this record and change max_status of previous record to False else no change required.

When you need to find out the instance of ComputerRecord with max 'ts' , query only on max_status=True

Comment: That's a good solution if you have low POST/inserts in ComputerRecord model, which is not the case. For each POST I would have to UPDATE the last ComputerRecord of the PC and then CREATE a new row. Nevertheless I will compare the efficiency with the other solutions. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
from django.db.models import Max, F

qs = ComputerRecord.objects.annotate(
    max=Max('pc__computerrecord__ts')
).filter(
    ts=F('max')
)
```

Yes, this form expression doesn't build the *exact* SQL query in the OP, but it produces the same result (there may be some performance issues, not sure about the matrics)

Alternatively, you can execute the raw SQL using the **`raw()`** method as

```
raw_query = """
SELECT hub_computerrecord.*
FROM hub_computerrecord
JOIN (
    SELECT pc_id, MAX(ts) AS max_ts
    FROM hub_computerrecord
    GROUP BY pc_id
) AS maxs ON hub_computerrecord.pc_id = maxs.pc_id
WHERE hub_computerrecord.ts = maxs.max_ts;
"""

qs = ComputerRecord.objects.raw(raw_query)
```

Comment: That's crazy inefficient because I have a lot of *ComputerRecord*

Comment: Yes, it is. But, afaik, Django ORM doesn't have that flexibility to obtain your *SQL query*. BTW, would you like to use the *raw SQL query* to get the *objects*?

Comment: If I use raw SQL it limits a bunch of other features like, django orm filters, url filters, custom filters, ect...

Comment: as I mentioned, *"Django ORM doesn't have that flexibility to obtain your SQL query"*